# What's the difference of symmetry between spin-1 photon and spin-1 triplet?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, group-theory

Can I treat  spin-1 photon and spin-1 triplet as equivalent in term of the same Lie group? Furthermore, we know that the effective model for Kondo lattice, i.e. Coqblin–Schrieffer model

$$H_{C S}=\sum_{k M} \epsilon_{k} c_{k M}^{\dagger} c_{k M}+J \sum_{k, k^{\prime}, M, M^{\prime}} c_{k M}^{\dagger} c_{k^{\prime} M^{\prime}}S_{M'M}$$ 
has $SU(N)$ symmetry due to the spin orbital coupling, and I am confused of the physical picture of  $SU(N)$ symmetry about spin system in reality.